# Different wsp file size each build

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

I have a SharePoint project running in VS.net 2008.  Each time when I build the wsp using WSP builder, the wsp file always turns out to be of different size.  Nothing was changed between builds.  This happens on all machines.

I was wondering what could be the reason behind it?  Does it have something to do with the way the files were packaged?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Below are the steps I performed to get this issue:

  -build project.

  -build wsp file.

  -check wsp file size.

  -delete wsp file.

Repeat that for n times on the same project.

The variation of wsp file size is no more than 100 bytes.  But if I build the same project using the same tool on the same machine, I would thought that the wsp file to come out the same size each time.

**More update**
I have done a file comparison between 2 wps files using a file diff tool (after renaming the wsp files into cabs and extracting the files).  There are 2 differences: one in the DLL file (which I can't read its all gibberish), and the other one in manifest file (just a difference in the time of build).

File size wise, all file sizes match up.  Might have been a hashing thing?

Comment: Rename the WSPs to CAB and compare the files inside (?)

Comment: Check if you are comparing between release and debug outputs ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by visual studio incrementing the version number each build. Which in turn leads to a different wsp file size because of the cab compression.

Check the Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, change the version attribute from 1.0.0.* to something static (1.0.0.0)

Comment: the values suggested are static to start with, so I don't think thats the cause of the problem.